# creating array of objects from given custom object in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
private void populateArrayOfObjects(Object[] params, Employee e){
params[0] = e.getName();
params[1] = e.getEmpId();
params[2] = e.getDesignation();
}
```

Is there any other way we can populate above array?

Comment: Why is your requirement written in Java code? What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: Where does that requirement come from and what is it meant for? I'd see several design flaws in it, one being that the parameter would have to be initialized with the correct size already.

Comment: before calling this method I have initialized the array as                           Object[] params = new Object[20]; populateArray(params,e);

Comment: You could use Reflection to read all values from a given Object into your Object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this ;

```
params = Arrays.asList(e.getName(), e.getEmpId(),e.getDesignation()).toArray();
```

Create a list as `Array.asList()`.And convert to array with `toArray()`. So you dont need to send to method. Just do with simple one line.